# React swap value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can you please give an example of how to swap values between two inputs, I made two inputs, and it is necessary that values ​​come from two identical components and if the value of the first is greater than the second, they swap places, I did it, but I think this is not the right solution.

I did it, but I think this is not the right solution.

ActiveContainer.jsx :

```
export const ActiveContainer = ({ type, context, active }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({ value1: 0, value2: 0 });
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);

  const validateInputed = () => {
    if (inputValue.value1 > inputValue.value2) {
      setValue2(inputValue.value1);
      setValue1(inputValue.value2);
    }
  };

  const setType = (containerType) => {
    switch (containerType) {
      case "checkbox":
        return <CheckBoxFilter context={context} />;
      case "inputs":
        return (
          <SubContainer>
            <InputFilter
              context={context}
              value1={value1}
              onValue={(value) => {
                setInputValue((state) => {
                  return { ...state, value1: value };
                });
              }}
              onChange={validateInputed}
              placeholderText="from"
            />{" "}
            -
            <InputFilter
              context={context}
              value2={value2}
              onValue={(value) => {
                setInputValue((state) => {
                  return { ...state, value2: value };
                });
              }}
              onChange={validateInputed}
              placeholderText="to"
            />
            {context.inputText ? context.inputText : ""}
          </SubContainer>
        );
      case "dropdowns":
        return (
          <SubContainer>
            <DropdownFilter context={context} placeholderText="from" />-
            <DropdownFilter context={context} placeholderText="to" />
            {context.inputText ? context.inputText : ""}
          </SubContainer>
        );
      default:
        throw new Error("Undefined type");
    }
  };

  return <Container active={active}>{setType(type)}</Container>;
};
```

InputFilter.jsx :

```
export const InputFilter = ({
  context,
  placeholderText,
  onValue,
  onChange,
  value1,
  value2,
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  const setFiled = ({ target }) => {
    let { value, min, max } = target;
    value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(value)));
    setValue(value);
    onValue(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(value1);
  }, [value1]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(value2);
  }, [value2]);

  const validateInputedData = () => {
    onChange();
  };

  return (
    <Input
      type="number"
      onChange={setFiled}
      onBlur={validateInputedData}
      value={value || ""}
      min={Math.min(Number(context.min), Number(context.min)) || ""}
      max={Math.max(Number(context.max), Number(context.max)) || ""}
      placeholder={placeholderText}
    />
  );
};
```